# How to sort by Alphabetical in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, alphabetical

I've been trying to sort a vector of Employee's with a string data member called last name. I've tried several different ways, using the sort method of vector, trying to convert my vectors to list and using its sorting, I even tried using string compare and > operators as shown below:

```
    vector<Employee>sortE(vector<Employee>record)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < record.size() - 1; i++)
        if (record[i].getLastName() > record[i+1].getLastName())
            swap(record[i], record[i + 1]);
    return record;
}
```

I thought if I used the above method with the swap function, it would work. But maybe since swap is a string method and I'm doing it with Employees it won't swap properly? But I've also tried it with my own "swap" like below:

```
vector<Employee>sortE(vector<Employee>record)
{
    Employee temp;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < record.size() - 1; i++)
        if (record[i].getLastName() > record[i + 1].getLastName())
        {
            temp = record[i];
            record[i] = record[i + 1];
            record[i + 1] = temp;
        }

    return record;
}
```

Either way I can't seem to get it to work properly, any insight or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have to write your own sorting code?  If so, neither of those above are correct.  See [here](http://www.sorting-algorithms.com/) for different sorting methods, or use std::sort.

Comment: No, I was just trying to find a way to sort it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a lambda if using C++11 or newer (also, I don't know what your Employee class looks like, so I made a trivial one). Also, check here for online execution: http://cpp.sh/6574i

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Employee
{
public:
    Employee( const std::string& firstName, const std::string& lastName ) :
        _firstName( firstName ),
        _lastName( lastName )
    {}

    ~Employee()
    {}

    std::string FirstName() const
    { 
        return _firstName;
    }

    std::string LastName() const
    {
        return _lastName;   
    }

    std::string FullName() const
    {
        return _firstName + " " + _lastName;   
    }

private:
    std::string _firstName;
    std::string _lastName;
};

int main()
{
    Employee e1( "Suresh", "Joshi" );
    Employee e2( "Mats", "Sundin" );
    Employee e3( "Steve", "Nash" );
    std::vector< Employee > employees { e1, e2, e3 };

    std::sort(employees.begin(), employees.end(), 
        [](const Employee& lhs, const Employee& rhs) -> bool
        { 
             return rhs.LastName() > lhs.LastName(); 
        });

    for ( auto employee : employees )
    {
        std::cout << employee.FullName() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ahhh, beaten to the punch by Tony.

Comment: but you bothered to supply a complete program... nice!

Comment: Thanks, I tried Ishamael's and it worked fine as far as i can tell, which seems similar to what you gave( not entirely though)

Comment: In C++, there's a ton of ways to do everything, just need to see what works best for you. Personally, if I just need one-offs, I would use a lambda to sort. I don't tend to override operators much, but that's just my preference.

Comment: @CodeLink: I went to upvote Ishamael's answer but sadly it's been deleted... it was basically sound but had been downvoted by someone, possibly because it copied then sorted the data, whereas it's usually desirable and more efficient to sort the data in-place: the client code can very easily copy if they want then apply an in-place sort so that's more flexible.

Comment: I tried to up vote it after i tried it, ( before yours and SJoshi's response showed up) but Im not allowed to up vote until i get like 15 rep or something

Comment: @CodeLink FYI: I just edited the answer to be a bit more C++11ish. Functions identically to the previous answer, but for example, I used the vector's initializer list, and improved the Employee class a bit.

Comment: Ah okay, I'm not which C I'm using, I just use visual studio as an IDE

Comment: @CodeLink C++11 is a recent version of the C++ standard (surpassing C++03, and was surpassed by C++14 recently). 

If you're using Visual Studio 2013, it has most of the C++11 standard working (things like initializer lists, foreach loops, lambdas, etc...). GCC 4.8 and higher also has most of it working.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a lambda to `std::sort`:

```
std::vector<Employee> ve;
using std::begin;
using std::end;
std::sort(begin(ve), end(ve),
          [](const Employee& lhs, const Employee& rhs)
          {
              return lhs.getLastName() < rhs.getLastName();
          });
```

That said, in real life last names are not necessarily unique, and when they compare equal it's a good idea to fall back on first name, and if that's also equal some other field like an employee id:

```
              return lhs.getLastName() < rhs.getLastName() ||
                     lhs.getLastName() == rhs.getLastName() &&
                     (lhs.getFirstName() < rhs.getFirstName() ||
                      lhs.getFirstName() == rhs.getFirstName() &&
                      lhs.getId() == rhs.getId());
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by providing a lambda, I'm fairly new to C++, but it seems a common theme amongst these answers to use const(s) and to return a comparison like e.lastname < h.lastname. I don't believe there is any const in my program though

Comment: The `[](const employee&...) { ... }` bit is the "lambda" - it's basically an in-place anonymous function definition, telling the `sort` algorithm how to compare two `Employee`s.  The lambda can accept the `Employee` parameters as `const` references because it doesn't need to modify the `Employee`s it's comparing - it just tells the algorithm how they compare, and the algorithm does the swapping/moving/whatever-it-needs-to-do.  Your `vector` itself should not be `const`, or the `sort` algorithm wouldn't be able to modify it into sorted order.